# Deploy to appengine with trusted connection?

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it possible to deploy an app to google appengine without it asking everytime for email/password, with a schema like the used by ssh trusted connection (using stored secure keys)?

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of what I was looking for:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#oauth

basically, you add this parameter to the command line:

```
appcfg.py --oauth2 update myapp/
```

and it redirects to a browser, you authenticate there and it stores a token so you don't need to login each time

Comment: Thanks for sharing your findings Sam.  I'll check out the article, as this was my next step.  One question Sam, what are you using for command line?  Do you just run these locally, or are you using a remote connection via putty, or just something in the App Engine Launcher?